# I unable to Insert a value from a char that has been CAST as Integer and added by 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I convert an `id` which is in a char column datatype. after that, I want to add it by 1 (plus 1).

Could you help me? why my query is not working?

query:

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `country_name`) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(CAST(`id` as INTEGER)) AS `max_id` FROM `countries`) + 1, 'India');
```

Comment: any error message you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would run:

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `country_name`) 
SELECT MAX(CAST(`id` as INTEGER)) + 1, 'India'
FROM `countries`;
```

But I think it would be easier if you just make the id column an [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: `IDENTITY` is a SQL Server, not a Mysql feature.

Comment: What's in a name, I linked to mysql documentation. (edited)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you should be doing identifiers.

If you want incrementing `id` values, you want to use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature when creating your table.

Your way is dangerous, there's always a possibility of two transactions running at the same time picking the same "next ID".

---

Just create a table with the flag on:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO countries (`name`) VALUES ('India');
```